# CMake object library target usage syntax

Tags: cmake

The [cmake documentation on object libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/command/add_library.html#object-libraries) states that (other) targets may reference an object library using the `$<objlib>` syntax (where `objlib` is the name of the object library):

```
add_library(foo OBJECT 
  foo.cpp
)

add_library(bar SHARED 
  bar.cpp
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:foo>
)
```

I would like to understand what the reason for the existence & need of the `TARGET_OBJECTS:foo` generator expression is? What exactly prevents cmake from being able to handle just this case:

```
add_library(foo OBJECT 
  foo.cpp
)

add_library(bar SHARED 
  bar.cpp
  foo
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add_library` requires you to list the files required for the linker to build your library. Since you're using an object library, there's no final object for `foo` to refer to, just a collection of objects.

Imagine a slightly more complex scenario:

```
add_library(foo OBJECT 
  fooA.cpp
  fooB.cpp
)

add_library(bar SHARED 
  barA.cpp
  barB.cpp
)

add_library(spaz SHARED
  foo
  bar
)
```

For the `spaz` directive, `bar` refers to a single `bar.so` (or DLL or whatever) that was linked by the respective `add_library`, but what does `foo` refer to? There's two files, `fooA.o` and `fooB.o`, and so cmake needs to use a generator expression to collect these.

I'm not certain if there's a technical reason that cmake *can't* support a shorthand for object libraries, but the current solution leverages the already existing generator expressions.